# SIlverStripe PHP - "Add new" or select existing in Dropdown

Tags: php, silverstripe

This should be relatively simple. I know how to create a form and hide it and show it if a specific `option` is selected

I want to have a `Dropdown` populated with a specific `DataObject`. That much is simple. But I need to add an option that says 'Add new' to this `Dropdown`, which is in a form

I can handle the submission (like if the value is something like 'new' instead of an `ID`), but I do not know how to add this option into the `select` with `Silverstripe`, or if it is even possible. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a DropdownField and populate it with whatever key value pairs you want. For example:

```
$itemsField = DropdownField::create(
    'Items',
    'Items',
    ['add-new' => 'Add new'] + $this->Items()->map()->toArray()
);
```

The third argument is an array that gets turned into the `option` html elements for the drop down.

Then you can add it to your form's `FieldList`:

```
$form = Form::create(
    $this, 
    'MyForm', 
    FieldList::create(
        [
            $someField,
            $someOtherField,
            $itemsField
        ]
    ), 
    $actions, 
    $requiredFields
);
```

http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-DropdownField.html

Answer (score 1):

A Dropdown for selecting a `$has_one` is fine. E.g. if you have a list of `Addresses` and want to select the `Country`.

Sometimes a new `Country` has to be added. For this i used the [quickaddnew extension](https://github.com/sheadawson/silverstripe-quickaddnew) which adds a nice button "add new" beneath the dropdown and opens a form in a modal for adding the new item. You can use it in your code like this:

```
public function getCMSFields() {
    /**
     * @FieldList
     */
    $fields =  parent::getCMSFields();

    $countries = function() {
        return Country::get()->map('ID','Title')->toArray();
    };

    $country = new DropdownField('CountryID', 'Country', $countries());
    $country->setEmptyString('-- please select --');
    $country->useAddNew('Country', $countries);
    $fields->insertAfter($country, 'Telephone');

    $fields->removeByName('SortOrder');

    return $fields;
```

Comment: @Barry what do you mean?